# BSOD verification of a known dll failed 0xc0000428

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I get this BSOD today. I has tried all basic solutions like F8, repair computer, last known comfiguration, bootrec /fixboot, etc. without any solutions. I have CBS.log which have some errors, but I dont know how to fix em, or what does they mean. Here is end of this log : http://pastebin.com/teyZGBNN

Any solution ?